# Using another class in same package but separate file

Tags: java, package

Edit: Followed advice from the comments and the answer below. I learned some helpful information and fixed the problem; it was a combination of improper compilation and of using my class name instead of it's variable declaration. Code is updated below.

---

This is my first time using packages in java, and this is confusing me. I am completely lost; how can I create an object from a class defined in another file? I've been searching through overflow and other sources but nothing has helped me yet.

This is my best attempt so far (the majority of code is left out): However, in Advisor.java my compiler says cannot find Symbol (Student) OR (Student[]) Every instance it's mentioned even though I clearly defined student in Student.java. My constructor in Student.java has to be public.

Student.java

```
package bookKeeping;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

final class Majors {
    public static String[] majors = null;
}

public final class Student {
    private static String fName;
    private static String mName;
    private static String lName;
    private static String classYear;
    private static String major;
    private static String ID;

    public Student() {
        this.fName = "First_Name";
        this.mName = "";
        this.lName = "Last_Name";
        this.classYear = "00/0000";
        this.major = "Undefined";
        this.ID = "0000-0000";
    }

    public static String ToString() {   
    }

    public static String SetNames(String name) {    
    }

    public static String SetID(String id) { 
    }

    public static String SetMajor(String m) {
    }

    public static String SetClassYear(String date) {    
    }
}
```

Advisor.java

```
package bookKeeping;

import bookKeeping.Student;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Construct {
    public static String[] names(String fileName) {
        String[] studentInfo = null;
        Student[] studentName = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        int a = 0, position = 0, lineSafe = 0;
        try {
            String line;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
            System.out.println("\nThis program assumes MM/dd/YYYY and MM/YYYY");

            line = reader.readLine();

            a = Integer.parseInt(line);
            studentInfo = new String[a];
            studentName = new Student[a];

            studentName[lineSafe] = new Student();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String kappa = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0: kappa = studentName[lineSafe].SetNames(line);
                            break;
                    case 1: kappa = studentName[lineSafe].SetID(line);
                            break;
                    case 2: kappa = studentName[lineSafe].SetMajor(line);
                            break;
                    case 3: kappa = studentName[lineSafe].SetClassYear(line);
                            break;
                }

                if (kappa != null) {
                    System.out.println(kappa);
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    position = 0;
                    studentInfo[lineSafe] = studentName[lineSafe].ToString();
                    studentName[++lineSafe] = new Student();                    
                } else {
                    position++;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("\nIOEXCEPTION\n");
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return studentInfo;
    }
}

public class Advisor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("\nError: Files missing from Command Line\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String[] studentInfo = Construct.names(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is: `Student[lineSafe] = new Student();` is not a valid statement

Comment: I was just trying to compile each separately (e.g. javac Student.java and javac Advisor.java). Let me know if you know how to compile this properly! Ok, I'll figure out why it's wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, I just fixed everything and it worked. A silly oversight; thanks RC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a syntax issue in the `Advisor.java`: you are indexing the class `Student` as if it were an array `Student[lineSafe]`, but it is not an array. I think you meant to use `studentInfo` array for that (and make it `Student[] studentInfo` instead of `String[] studentInfo`; `studentNames` should become an array of `String`s, too).

Don't forget to assign `new Student[MAX_STUDENT]` to `studentInfo` to avoid runtime errors.

Once you are done with the syntax, create a specific file structure in order for this to compile:

- Make a folder called `bookKeeping`
- Move `Student.java` to `bookKeeping`
- Move `Advisor.java` to `bookKeeping`
- Go to the parent folder of `bookKeeping`, and run `javac`

On Windows, you would run the compiler like this:

```
javac bookKeeping\Student.java
```

(on UNIX and Mac you would reverse the backslash).

You need to do this because `javac` assumes that java files for each package are placed in folders that correspond to that package name, in `.java` files that match the name of public class inside the file.

Comment: Ok, I did that and ran 'javac Student.java Advisor.java' in my new bookKeeping directory. This removed half of my errors; however, I am still getting the error Cannot Find Symbol for instances with Student[lineSafe].

Comment: @user3834916 You should be running `javac` command from the parent directory of `bookKeeping` directory (see the edit).

Comment: Ok, so I'm at the parent folder and I run: 'javac bookKeeping\Student.java' and then run 'javac bookKeeping\Advisor.java'. This produces the same result as when I run 'javac Student.java Advisor.java' IN bookKeeping after successfully compiling Student.java. I still get Symbol not found errors upon compiling Advisor.java for some reason. OH, I'm not smart, I didn't use studentNames for each of my objects, so it isn't valid. See RC's comment above.